# c# regex how to match user's input to an array of words/phrases

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, match

I have an array with different words and phrases. The user will input a spam message and I'm supposed to check whether there are any matches to the words and phrases already in the array. For each match the score will +1 and if the score is more than 5 then the possibility of it being a spam message is Yes.

My score doesn't increase though and I'm not sure why.

```
string[] spam = new string[] {"-different words and phrases provided by programmer"};

        Console.Write("Key in an email message: ");
        string email = Console.ReadLine();
        int score = 0;

        string pattern = "^\\[a-zA-Z]";
        Regex expression = new Regex(pattern);
        var regexp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

        if (!regexp.IsMatch(email))
        {
            score += 1;
        }
```

Comment: If you want to count non-letters, the regex must be `string pattern = "[^a-zA-Z]";`. Or even `\P{L}`. Or use `Char.IsLetter()`. You declare `spam` var, but you are not using it. Are the words inside to be tested against somehow?

Comment: You'll only get +1 in your current code if you match ["\" literally at the start of user input, follwed by a single letter](https://regex101.com/r/zE1bQ0/1), and don't use `spam` at all. Are you sure that's what you need?

Comment: You don't need to use regex, you can just check if the users string contains any of the words.

Comment: spam array is declared but not used anywhere in your code?

Comment: Also, `expression` and `regexp` are identical. I think you wanted to write `string[] spam = new string[] {"different", "words", "and", "phrases", "provided", "by", "programmer"};`

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string[] spam = new string[] { "test", "ak", "admin", "againadmin" };
                string email = "Its great to see that admin ak is not perfroming test.";
                string email1 = "Its great to see that admin ak is not perfroming test againadmin.";

                if (SpamChecker(spam, email))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("email spam");
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("email not spam");
                }

                if (SpamChecker(spam, email1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("email1 spam");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("email1 not spam");
                }

                Console.Read();
            }

            private static bool SpamChecker(string[] spam, string email)
            {
                int score = 0;
                foreach (var item in spam)
                {
                    score += Regex.Matches(email, item, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
                    if (score > 3) // change count as per desired count
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Linq* to solve the problem

```
  // HashSet<String> is for better performance
  HashSet<String> spamWords = new HashSet<String>(
    "different words and phrases provided by programmer"
      .Split(new Char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(word => word.ToUpper()));

  ...

  String eMail = "phrases, not words and letters zzz";

  ... 

  // score == 3: "phrases" + "words" + "and"
  int score = Regex
    .Matches(eMail, @"\w+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value.ToUpper())
    .Sum(word => spamWords.Contains(word) ? 1 : 0);
```

In this implementation I'm looking for spam words in *case insensitive* manner (so `And`, `and`, `AND` will be count as spam words). To take *plurals*, *ings* (i.e. `word`, `wording`) into account you have to use *stemmer*.