# How do I count the number of noise words in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Suppose I have a list of noise words...

```
string[] noise = new[] {"and", "it", "in"}; // etc, etc
```

...and I have a string `s`. I want to know how many noise words exist in `s`.

I know can do this by splitting `s` on spaces, then looping through the resultant array checking for matches in `noise`, but this seems like a very inefficient way of doing it. It feels like there ought to be a neat RegEx or Linq way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069513/c-sharp-regex-how-to-match-users-input-to-an-array-of-words-phrases and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings

Comment: Are the words always separated by a string? What about punctuation? Also what makes you think Linq or RegEx will be any better?

Comment: Does it have to be a list? If the words are constant (ie. not user input), you could write a regex like `\b(?:and|it|in)\b` and count the number of matches

Comment: @DavidG Yes the words are separated by spaces, no there isn't any punctuation (this is an unusual case, but wasn't worth explaining as it didn't really affect the question), and I didn't say that Linq or RegEx would necessarily be better, I was looking for a more elegant and/or efficient way to code it, and suggested those as obvious candidates. Tim's answer is just what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ isn't more efficient than a loop but often more readable and concise and i guess that's what you wanted. In this case you  can use `Enumerable.Count` and `Contains`:

```
int countNoiseWords = s.Split().Count(noise.Contains);
```

The case-insensitive way:

```
int countNoiseWords = s.Split()
    .Count(w => noise.Contains(w, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

If the `noise`-list is very long you should consider to use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a list.

Comment: "I know can do this by splitting s on spaces, then looping through the resultant array checking for matches in noise"...

Comment: @Evk: yes, but he wanted a LINQ way because its more concise.

Comment: Worth using a HashSet probably by the way, who knows how long is that noise list.

Comment: @Evk The noise list is pretty short in my case, so the HashSet isn't needed. I wasn't specifically looking for Linq or RegEx, I just wanted to see if there was a more elegant and/or efficient way of coding. This works perfectly.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel beware that if there is any punctuation - this will give false negatives. For example "Test.It burns" - "it" will not be counted.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: Evk is right. If you want that you could use the [`Split` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a `String[]`. Store everything that counts as a word delimiter in this array.

Comment: @Evk Good point. As it happens, my case doesn't involve any punctuation (see my earlier reply to DavidG's comment on my question). Worth noting for other cases though.